# React Native IOS App crashes when no network conection

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

On the simulator it does not crash and Alerts the error, but in production it is crashes as soon as fetch request suppose to be made and it is impossible to reopen the app until network connection is back (I turn on/off airplane mode for the testing)

here are the snippets of my code

```
  componentWillMount: function(){
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change',this.handleConnectivityChange)
    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done((data) => {

    this.setState({
      isConnected: data
    })
    console.log('this.state.isConnected: ', this.state.isConnected);
  })
 },

handleConnectivityChange: function(){
  var connected = this.state.isConnected ? false : true
  this.setState({isConnected: connected})
  console.log('this.state.isConnected11: ', this.state.isConnected);
},

....

goToList: function(replace, listview){
  console.log('this.state.isConnected: ', this.props.isConnected);
  if (!this.props.isConnected){
    AlertIOS.alert('Error', 'Please check your network connectivity')
    this.props.removeFetching()
    return
  }
 ....
 fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
 ....
  .catch((error) => {
  StatusBarIOS.setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible(false)
  AlertIOS.alert('Error', 'Please check your network connectivity')
  this.props.removeFetching()
 })
.done()
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time trying to find a way to catch exceptions when using fetch() but I was unable to get it working (e.g. using .catch() or a try/catch blog didn't work). What did work was to use XMLHttpRequest with a try/catch blog instead of fetch(). Here's an example I based off of: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#using-other-networking-libraries

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
  if (request.readyState !== 4) {
    return;
  }

  if (request.status === 200) {
    console.log('success', request.responseText);
    var responseJson = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    // *use responseJson here*
  } else {
    console.warn('error');
  }
};
try {
  request.open('GET', 'https://www.example.org/api/something');
  request.send();
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```